# PublicKeyToken=null in the data

Tags: c#, custom-controls, resx, publickeytoken

I have a C# CustomControl that is compiled into my project. I get the error:

"Invalid Resx file. Type GradientOptions, Calculator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Calculator PublicKeyToken=null in the data at line 167, position 4 cannot be located. Line 169, position 5"

Lines in question are from the form where I have the control added "frmCalculator.resx" and are as follows:

```
  <assembly alias="Calculator" name="Calculator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <data name="btnA.Gradient" type="GradientOptions, Calculator">
    <value>False; Black; Blue; Horizontal</value>
  </data>
```

How can I get this to get past this error?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: probably you might have incompatible versions of some references of that particular assembly...such as nuget dll hell kind of thing